# A formula for the dual Coxeter number

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\Phi$ be the root system of a finite dimensional simple Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, with dual Coxeter number $h^\vee$.

Let $\alpha_0\in \Phi$ be a long root
 (if all the roots have the same length, then let $\alpha_0\in \Phi$ be any root).

Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be the basic inner product (the inner product according to which $\langle\alpha_0,\alpha_0\rangle=2$).

> Then I believe that the following formula is true:           
> $
> \displaystyle\sum_{\alpha\in\Phi}\,\, \langle \alpha,\alpha_0\rangle^2=4h^\vee
> $

How does one prove that formula?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to sum in your sum over only the *simple* roots (not all the roots)? That would look more like what I've seen as the definition of the dual Coxeter number.

Comment: You normalise lengths in $\mathsf G_2$ so that the short roots have squared length $2/3$?

Comment: @LSpice: Yes indeed. In type $G_2$, the squared length of the short roots is $2/3$, according to my conventions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Weyl invariance, it suffices to prove this for *some* long root.  When $\alpha_0$ is the highest root, it is an immediate consequence of Lemma 4 of [Suter - Coxeter and dual Coxeter numbers](https://doi.org/10.1080/00927879808826122), which states that $h^\vee\alpha_0 = \sum_{\alpha \in \Phi_+} \langle\alpha, \alpha_0^\vee\rangle\alpha$.